# Is it possible to deploy an uncompiled ASP.NET Razor Pages website?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am wondering if it is possible to copy the source code of an ASP.NET Razor Pages website to a Windows web server and for it to run without it needing to be published/compiled?

Similar to what you can do with ASP.NET Web Forms websites where you upload the source code (*.aspx and *.aspx.cs files) and they compile at runtime?

I saw something about `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` but I wasn't sure if this is what I was after and how to use it.

Is this possible and any guidance or links on how to do it?

PS. I'm sure this is not good practice, but would still like an answer... Thanks.

Comment: Is there any update on this for .Net Core 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible and any guidance or links on how to do it?
>
> *PS. I'm sure this is not good practice, but would still like an answer*

There's a way to allow deploy "uncompiled" `*.cshtml`. Assuming you're using ASP.NET Core 3.1:

1. First of all, add a package reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`:

   ```xml
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.*" />
   ```
2. Change your services to allow Runtime Compilation:

   ```
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```
3. Configure a custom Task to copy the source code to publish dir in your **`*.csproj`** file:

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Pages\**\*.cshtml" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
       <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)" 
         DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Pages\%(RecursiveDir)" 
       />
   </Target>
   ```

#### Demo

I publish a RazorPage WebApp and host it on `IIS`. And then we can change the `Pages/**/*.cshtml` views dynamically:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm giving it a go but having some issues, maybe because my host only supports 3.0. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: @johna I believe it is not true because I just create project using  ASP.NET Core `3.0.100` and find that it works fine for me. So Could you please show us how you deploy the app? Did you see a `Pages/` folder in the publish folder when deploying?  Or are you launching the site in VS?

Comment: I made the changes to the csproj and startup.cs and published to a folder. It did then include the Pages folder and I copied all via FTP but I got an error that said something to do with wrong version. I've been meaning to try again when I had a spare moment, so I'll start with a new clean project and try again and post back with the results.

Comment: "something to do with wrong version": What's that error message? My best guess you should use `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.0.*" />` instead of `3.1.*`

Comment: This time I created a new 3.0 project with the default pages and made the .csproj and startup.cs changes, and added Runtime Compilation via Nuget. It worked! Thank you. I see only .cshtml files can be edited and not the .cs files... I guess there's no way of making them compile at runtime too?

Comment: @johna I haven't found any easy ways to compile `*.cs` files at run-time so far. Something hacking might work, but I wonder whether it deserves?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the project settings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887228/111266) seem to allow you to publish the cshtml files without a custom step. What do you think?

Comment: @JoeEnos I didn't know there's a way to use `<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory/>` to achieve this goal.  But I believe [Martin Ullrich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61887228/10091607) is right. BTW, do you happen to know if there's an official document link about `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory`?  :) I can't find a description about it.

Comment: @itminus I've been looking for any kind of documentation on this, and your answer and Martin's answer were the only things I could find. Both seem to work well. I've been super confused about this - there's plenty of documentation about how to compile views at runtime, except you don't actually get the views when you publish? So what's the purpose of that runtime compilation if you can't actually change the views...

Comment: @JoeEnos Hmm, I find [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-the-razor-sdk): "When true, copies RazorGenerate items (.cshtml) files to the publish directory. Typically, Razor files aren't required for a published app if they participate in compilation at build-time or publish-time. Defaults to false"