# Publish extra files in Core 3 - before I could use publishOptions (project.json)

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement "Feature folders/slices" in my project...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/september/asp-net-core-feature-slices-for-asp-net-core-mvc

In the link above they write:

```
To support publishing correctly, you’ll also need to update project.json’s publishOptions to include the Features folder:

JavaScript

Copy
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/*.cshtml",
    "Features/**/*.cshtml",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

But project.json and publishOptions does not exists in Core 3.

How can I solve this in Core 3?

Answer (score 1):

This post solved my problem...

[Is it possible to deploy an uncompiled ASP.NET Razor Pages website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59279396/is-it-possible-to-deploy-an-uncompiled-asp-net-razor-pages-website)

Add reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`.

Add startup `services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`.

In Properties -> PublishProfiles -> YourProfile.pubxml, add...

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Features\**\*.cshtml" />
    <JsFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Features\**\*.js" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Features\%(RecursiveDir)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(JsFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Features\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

And that's it :)