# MSBuild does not copy views to the output folder

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

After upgrading to .NET Core 3.1, my home-made build system broke. Here's the problem. I use MSBuild to publish a project in a CI/CD pipeline. This is my code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" C:\Company\Solution\Solution.sln /t:UserPanel /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=DeployUserPanel /p:SolutionDir=C:\Company\Solution /property:PublishFolder=C:\Publish\Solution\UserPanel /t:Publish
```

The exact same code would publish `.cshtml` files to the output directory in .NET Core 2.2. But now I need to manually copy/paste them from my `UserPanel` project into the publish folder, which breaks the CI/CD automation of course.

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core moved to pre-compiling the cshtml files so they are no longer needed in production. You will see that there should also be a `[YourApp].Views.dll` in the publish output which contains the compiled views.

If you absolutely need the old behavior, refer to [Razor file compilation in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli) for documentation on configuring Razor runtime compilation.

It comes down to changing the csproj to

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And changing your Startup.cs to include `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` on the call to configure MVC:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      services.AddControllersWithViews()
          .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
  }
```

Comment: For people like me who wants to find the docs about `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory`: see [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-the-razor-sdk) : "When true, copies RazorGenerate items (.cshtml) files to the publish directory. Typically, Razor files aren't required for a published app if they participate in compilation at build-time or publish-time. Defaults to false."